# I've been using the alert function for checking variables. Is there a better solution?

Tags: javascript, performance

remember, I am a beginner. So I have been using the alert(variable_here)
function to check and make sure any variables I a changing are doing what they are supposed to while I am coding. For example:

```
var randomevariable = (2)//set the variable
randomvariable = (randomvariable + 1)
alert(randomvariable)//see how I used the alert function as temporary statement for checking the variable?
```

Is there a better way to view a variable than document.write and alert?

Comment: You will really want to learn about all the developer tools available in your browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console

Comment: Is there a better tool than `alert`? Oh there's _just_ the browser's developer tools (F12), with the full console that can log not only strings but also objects and fold/unfold them and supports styling, the network tab to inspect and monitor all network activity, the debugger, the source inspector, etc etc so... yeah, there's a better way than alert :) Welcome learner, be prepared to have your mind blown every day or so.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using console.log or the debugger statement:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Debugging using a modern browser also helps:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the web browser's console, typically accessible with Right click > Inspect.
To print anything in the console while the code is running, you can put this in Javascript:

```js
console.log(randomvariable)
```

This is less disruptive than alert!

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in a browser environment, console.log() is going to give you an easier time than using alert() - using Chrome and most other modern browsers, you can press CTRL+Shift+I to open Chrome Dev Tools to see the chrome console and see the output of console.log() there.
[image]

There are some cases when debugging more complex bugs I also like to put variables on the window object - this gives them a global scope and lets me check their value at any given moment.

For example: `window.myVar = myVar;`

Then, later, when I want to check the value while debugging, you can go into the same chrome dev tools and type `window.myVar` to see their value.